Select and convert columns to write_dataset in Arrow
Everyone,
I want to convert columns and select them in csv files of different years into parquet format.
(The reason arrow is used here is because it is difficult to import data into R if it exceeds 30GB)
If I only use select columns, I can export it, but if I use schema to change the columns format and selection them to export, some problems will occur.
I'm using mtcars profile to simulate the problem I'm having, can anyone help me overcome it?
What I hope is to be able to complete it at the same time without importing data into R and selecting columns and converting columns formats and exporting them to parquet.
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)


# 1 select column to save
data(mtcars)

mtcars0 <- mtcars %>%
  slice(1:10)

mtcars1 <- mtcars %>%
  slice(11:20)

mtcars2 <- mtcars %>%
  slice(21:32)

write.csv(mtcars0, file = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\mtcars0.csv", row.names = F)
write.csv(mtcars1, file = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\mtcars1.csv", row.names = F)
write.csv(mtcars2, file = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\mtcars2.csv", row.names = F )

mtcars <- open_csv_dataset("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\mtcars.csv") %>%
  select(mpg, cyl, disp)

mtcars <- list.files("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop", full.names = TRUE,
                 pattern = "^mtcars[0-2]\\.csv$") %>%
  file.path() %>%
  open_csv_dataset() %>%
  select(mpg, cyl, disp)

mtcars

mtcars_all <- mtcars %>%
  collect()

write_parquet(mtcars, "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\mtcars_select.parquet")

mtcars_select <- open_dataset("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\mtcars_select.parquet")
mtcars_select 

#>FileSystemDataset with 1 Parquet file
#>mpg: double
#>cyl: int64
#>disp: double


# 2 convert columns type to save
mtcars <- list.files("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop", full.names = TRUE,
                     pattern = "^mtcars[0-2]\\.csv$") %>%
  file.path() %>%
  open_csv_dataset(schema = schema(mpg = string(),
                                       cyl = string(),
                                       disp = string())) %>%
  select(mpg, cyl, disp)

write_parquet(mtcars, "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\mtcars_select2.parquet")

#>error: Invalid: Could not open CSV input source 
#>'C:/Users/user/Desktop/mtcars0.csv': Invalid: CSV parse error
#>: Row #1: Expected 3 columns, got 11: "mpg","cyl","disp","hp","drat",
#>"wt","qsec","vs","am","gear","carb"

